# My state updates are not working in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, react-context

My code is not working expected. Here are the details for the same:
NewUserContext has a value of newUserData and NewUserDispatchContext has a value of setNewUserData.

[image]

Now when I type something in input box then the setValue function gets executed and the new formed object gets console.log due to the line I marked in BasicInformation.jsx but in Profile.jsx useEffect is not working you can see the attached images

[image]

[image]

[image]

Github repo - https://github.com/Team-Antern/Antern-Website
BasicInformation.jsx - https://github.com/Team-Antern/Antern-Website/blob/master/src/Components/DashboardMain/Profile/BasicInformation/BasicInformation.jsx
Profile.jsx - https://github.com/Team-Antern/Antern-Website/blob/master/src/Components/DashboardMain/Profile/Profile.jsx

I have attached the code so that you can look over it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary** to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry @romellem I would take care of this thing in next question. The problem is now fixed. Thanks a lot for your time.